# angular-selectize form's validation

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive, selectize.js

I'm searching to set validation for an input caused by angular-selectize directive (https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize).

The problem is that this directive:

```
<selectize config="pic.interGermConfig" options="pic.interGermOptions" data-ng-model="pic.interGermFilter"></selectize>
```

Produces this output:

```
<selectize config="pic.interGermConfig" options="pic.interGermOptions" data-ng-model="pic.interGermFilter"></selectize>
<div class=“selectize-control”>
 <div class=“selectize-input items not-full”>
      <div data-value=“value” class=“item”>Visual value</div>
      <input type=“text” autocomplete=“off” placeholder=“” />
 </div>
 <div class=“selectize-dropdown multi”>
      <div class=“selectize-dropdown-content”>
           <div data-value=“value” data-selectable class=“option”>Visual value</div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

This tag:

```
<input type=“text” autocomplete=“off” placeholder=“” />
```

doesn't have ng-model directive property, so I can't use a custom directive with ngModel require, to set input validity.

Is it possible to do this in some way or is it possible sets input validity inside a controller rather that inside a directive?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution for my needs, but I think this isn't the best way to do this.

In a first moment, I've tried to use $watch on model passed to selectize directive, but this it's not allowed because ng-model attribute is obscured and not propagated to the new DOM element when use selectize.

So, looking angular-selectize code, I've seen that directive allows to use ng-required attribute (https://github.com/ptesser/angular-selectize/blob/master/dist/angular-selectize.js).
So I've created a function to checks model and sets errors in the controller and then I've passed this function to ng-require.

```
<selectize config="pic.interGermConfig" options="pic.interGermOptions"
           data-ng-model="pic.interGermFilter"
           data-ng-required="pic.checkSelectizeRequire(pic.interGermFilter, 'germs')">
</selectize>
```

And this is the function

```
function checkSelectizeRequire(array, filter){

  array = array === undefined ? [] : array;

  if (array.length === 0){
    vm.errorFilter[filter] = true;

  }else{
    vm.errorFilter[filter] = false;
    vm.dirtyFilter[filter] = true;
  }
}
```

To check errors in the form, I've created my own variables, because I don't know how check 'required' option for selectize input like classic way:

```
form.inputName.$error.required
```